# Is there an equivalent of a B-corp in Ireland or Estonia?

Tags: european-union, corporate-law, ireland, incorporation

Is there anything like a [benefit corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefit_corporation) in the EU, particularly in Ireland or Estonia?

If so, how does a B-corp or its analogue in either/each country differ from an [LLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_liability_company)?

Comment: According to [this](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefit_corporation), Italy is the only EU country (apparently the second country world-wide) that has introduced a Benefit Company statute.